# show textbox text when it change from code behind

Tags: c#, webforms, textbox, xmpp

Currently, am working on client chat server application, when a message is receive from any friend, it must show in textbox. 
when a message is receive below code execute, however the message has not been displayed on front end(textbox).

```
public void OnMessageReceieve(string message)
{
   //object of textbox
    txtMessage.Text += "Incoming messages";
    txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text + message;
}
```

above code execute on mentioned event

```
_xmppClientConnection.OnMessage+= new agsXMPP.protocol.client.MessageHandler(XmppCon_OnMessage);

public void  XmppCon_OnMessage(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message messsage)
{
    _xmppClientMessage= messsage;
    _iOnMessageReceiveListener.OnMessageReceieve(_xmppClientMessage.Body);
}
```

Comment: how you can doing this? fromm where On messageReceive Function called ?

Comment: I believe the textbox is not updated because you are trying to access a Control (the TextBox) outside of the UI thread. To resolve this, use: this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    txtMessage.Text += "Incoming messages";
    txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text + message;
});

Comment: am using web form how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
public void OnMessageReceieve(string message)
{
   //object of textbox
   this.txtMessage.Text = "Incoming messages " + message;
}
```

Comment: text is concatenating correctly but it is not display? on front end